# set same layout_height edittext and imagebutton

Tags: android, android-layout

My app has one EditText and ImageButton in LinearLayout.

I want to set layout_height EditText which is ImageButton.

ImageButton has src image and set layout_height is wrap_content.

How set to EditText 's layout_height same Imagebutton's src?

Comment: Your Question is not at all clear. Please try to elaborate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the solution if The alignment is **horizontal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:src="@drawable/mail"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I want to set  same height,not width.

Comment: Have you tried it ... its giving you the same height..It will work only if you are aligning them horizontally.. posting the resulting layout image

Answer (score 0):

I think for what your trying to do you should set the Linear Layout to layout_width and layout_height "wrap_content" then when you put the ImageView in set both to wrap_content then for the editText set the layout_height to match_parent then it will be the same as the ImageView

my bad i thought you said ImageView i could be wrong